# Use for loop with UIAnimation in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uianimation

I want to show number in a `UILabel` from an unknown number to unknown number. Suppose from 40 to 699. I want to show this one by one and then break the loop sequence when required number is arrived.

> E.g {40,41,42...667,668,669}

I want to remove the previous number from the label and add new number to the label object.
I am confuse to use `UIAnimation` in `for() Loop`.
Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: blinking animation you want ?

Comment: Yup blinking animation.

Comment: In short i want to create my custom timer, but its not a timer i want to show number of users registered on my server.

Comment: Bellowing answer working or not ?

Comment: Yes sir it works just the way i need. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using timer to animation with increase counter.

```
    int loopCount;
    NSTimer *myTimer;

    // Method that calls your timer.
    - (void)doStuff {

        loopCount++;.
        self.yourLabel.alpha = 0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.65 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
        self.yourLabel.alpha = 1;
        } completion:nil];

        if (loopCount >= 669) {
            [myTimer invalidate];
            myTimer = nil;
            self.yourLabel.alpha = 0;
        }
    }

    // Method that kicks it all off
    - (IBAction)startDoingStuff {
        myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.75
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(doStuff)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];
    }
```

Comment: It Works. Thanks a lot sir.